# Why does official nginx alpine docker not use the standard repository?

Tags: docker, nginx

Looking at https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/f8fad321cf58d5cbcafa3d9fa15314b8a77b5e65/mainline/alpine/Dockerfile it's clear that the official nginx repo doesn't use the `nginx` that's available in alpine's repositories, but instead seems to compile from scratch.  You can install nginx on any container using `apk add --update --no-cache nginx`.  **Why wouldn't nginx juse utilize this and maintain the official alpine repo?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the maintainer wants more control over the install of the main component of the image. That control lets them:

- Install a specific version
- Install with container specific options
- Avoid including packaging values that do not apply to containers, like startup scripts

One of the bigger reasons I can think of is to install a version immediately after it's release and before the package maintainers have had a chance to create a package for that release.

Answer (score 0):

This act has some answer.like:

- probably! nginx package in apk is not official and they want to configure and compile their self nginx
- Or they add additional configure option to nginx image!